# FastAPI SQLAlchemy - ManyToMany Relation Conflict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, fastapi

I have two main models: **user** and **post**

```py
class User(Base):
    """
        User Model
    """
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)

    posts = relationship("Post", back_populates="user")
    comments = relationship("Comment", back_populates="user")


class Post(Base):
    """
        Post Model
    """
    __tablename__ = "post"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(256), unique=True)
    body = Column(String(1024))

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")
    comments = relationship("Comment", back_populates="post")
```

As the documentation has recommended we can split our **ManyToMany** relations into two **OneToMany** relations between main models and one **associated** model. Link: [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)

Then I created this associated model

```py
class Comment(Base):
    """
        Comment Model
    """
    __tablename__ = "comment"

    user_id = Column(ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True)

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="comments")
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="comments")

    comment = Column(String(512))
```

and this code for post a comment

```py
def leave_comment(comment: str, user_id: int, post_id: int, db: Session):
    """
        Leave Comment On A Post
    """
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    post = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id == post_id).first()

    db_comment = models.Comment(
        comment,
        # user_id=user_id,
        # image_id=image_id,
    )
    db_comment.user = user
    db_comment.post = post

    db.add(db_comment)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_comment)
    return db_comment
```

When I'm trying to leave a comment on a post by using above function i will get this error

`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "comment_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (user_id, post_id)=(1, 1) already exists.`

`[SQL: INSERT INTO comment (user_id, post_id, comment) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(post_id)s, %(comment)s)]    [parameters: {'user_id': 1, 'post_id': 1, 'comment': 'my comment about image 1'}]`

Where is the problem is?

Comment: Your table structure assumes that a user can only add one single comment - since you have `post_id` and `user_id` as a composite primary key. When you attempt to add the second comment and one already exists, you'll get an error. If you want to allow multiple comments, add an integer field (with auto increment) as the primary key instead, and add a regular index on `(post_id, user_id)`.

Comment: I added a new integer column and set it as the primary key but I got the same error when I wanted to add a new comment for the same post!

Comment: You have to _remove (drop) the table_ and call `create_all` again if you change the definition of a table, unless you're using a migration solution such as `alembic` to create and run migrations between different versions of your database schema. Otherwise the old definition (and primary keys) will still be present.

Comment: I'm using alembic. I deleted all of the stored data on the table and run the alembic command. When a new integer field is added to the table, I ran the API again and  I got the same error for user_id and post_id duplication!

Comment: Do you still have the unique index for the two fields? Check the actual database structure and whether your migrations remove that requirement and that it actually ads the new `id` field.

Comment: I have 3 different `primary_key` for `comment_id`, `user_id` and `post_id`

Comment: `user_id` and `post_id` shouldn't be part of the primary key any longer; `comment_id` also needs to be an auto_increment column unless you want to assign a different unique id.